# Adapting ./configure step in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, configure

Is it neccessary to add some arguments to ./configure executable to include all the tools and libraries qt5.5.1 contains? Something like:

**./configure -qt-multimediawidgets -qt-webkitwidgets** ?

How to add or disable some libraries when doing **./configure**?

Comment: By configuring you mean for end-user or for development purpose ?

Comment: @BenjaminDebotté for development purpose.

Comment: Have you cloned Qt's source with Git?

Comment: @Mitch no I downloaded it from qt.io site, and trying to install it from source.

Comment: @Junior Oh you were talking about build Qt sources ? Be more precise next time, your question is ambiguous.
Did you follow the step specified here ? (Windows : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html)

Comment: Sorry I am in problem and I forgot to include some important stuffs in my question. I am doing this on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

At least with builds from Git, you can use `init-repository`'s `--module-subset` argument:

```
perl init-repository --module-subset=qtbase,qtxmlpatterns,qtdeclarative
```

The existence of those modules at configure time determines whether or not they'll be built. You could try the same thing with the source archive; just delete the top-level directories of modules that you're not interested in.